# Ninject and AutoMapper

Tags: ninject, silverlight-5.0, automapper-2

I'm throwing together some code for an internal demo which consists of a Silverlight 5.0 UI built on Caliburn.Micro.

**Summary Scenario:** 
I'm attempting to get AutoMapper to map a list of view models from a service proxy class. The view models have a ctor dependancy so I want to use Ninject to resolve this.

**Details:**
I have a parent view model (AvailableItemsViewModel) which makes a call to a service. It then maps the list of DTO's returned to AvailableItemViewModel using AutoMapper.

The AvailableItemViewModel takes a reference to Caliburn's IEventAggregator - as the view model will publish an event based on user input.

I've read:

[Injecting AutoMapper dependencies using Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615095/injecting-automapper-dependencies-using-ninject)

[AutoMapper with Ninject confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938740/automapper-with-ninject-confusion)

[How to configure Automapper to be injected with Ninject 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401303/how-to-configure-automapper-to-be-injected-with-ninject-2-0)

All of which seem fairly similar... so i've ended up with the following in my Bootstrap class:

```
 public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ITypeMapFactory>().To<TypeMapFactory>();

            foreach (var mapper in MapperRegistry.AllMappers())
                Bind<IObjectMapper>().ToConstant(mapper);

            Bind<ConfigurationStore>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("mappers", ctx => ctx.Kernel.GetAll<IObjectMapper>());
            Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ConfigurationStore>());
            Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ConfigurationStore>());
            Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<MappingEngine>();

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t=>Kernel.Get(t));                
            });

        }
    }
```

If i set a breakpoint in the bootstrapper, i see that Ninject can successfully create an instance of the AvailableItemViewModel.

Error is:

{System.ArgumentException: Type 'Caliburn.Proto.ViewModels.AvailableItemViewModel' does not have a default constructor
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
   at AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Type t)
   at TvdP.Collections.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at AutoMapper.DelegateFactory.CreateCtor(Type type)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.ObjectCreator.CreateObject(Type type)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.CreateObject(ResolutionContext context)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.NewObjectPropertyMapMappingStrategy.GetMappedObject(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)
   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)}

So Ninject is not being used?

Code to do the mapping is:

```
var availItems = Mapper.Map<List<Item>, List<AvailableItemViewModel>>(shoppingListStore.GetAvailableItems().ToList());

AvailableItems = new ObservableCollection<AvailableItemViewModel>(availItems);
```

What am i missing?

(AutoMapper is ver 2.1.267.0, Ninject is 3.0.0.0. I'm also using Ninject.Conventions)

**[Update]**
I note that the "workaround" in the post [AutoMapper with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559026/automapper-with-ninject?rq=1) also works for me.

**[Update]**
Given this:
Mapper.CreateMap().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();

If i remove the ConstructUsingServiceLocator() method then the breakpoint on Kernel.Get:

```
cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t=>Kernel.Get(t));
```

does not trigger. So it appears both are required?